# making efficient implementation of this Java MouseListener Logic

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, event-listener

I have a MouseListener Thread where this method is called each time there is a click:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){

    //my Logic here

}
```

Now what happens is that there are so many clicks in little time, while my logic here, takes more time to process. What i was expecting is that further clicks will be discarded and this method will continue on the latest upcoming clicks.

But what is happening that while the logic is processing, the incoming clics are queued and even when clicking is stopped, qued clicks keep calling this mousePressed method, as a result i have multiple delayed executions.

Unfortunatelly i do not have control over the Listener (why it ques and keep sending delayed clicks), so in such a scenario, can you tell me what is the efficient way of handling such that i do not make a que due to delay in my processing.

I think the most obvious way would be using another thread, but i am wondering this might trigger so many threads in little time, or is there any way i can lock just one thread while the rest of clicks just go through empty loop?

Comment: You might want to emulate how Swing handles repaint requests -- it ignores requests when they stack up. Please have a look here for more on this: [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/). And yes, I think regardless, you'll want to use a background thread, probably a thread pool.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, this is JNI method where actual mouse listener is from native code, there is no Swing involved.

Comment: Ok so if i simply start a new thread then calling the method, atleast i don't miss any of the click, although still the results are delayed and in many parallel threads, i guess using some volatile boolean flag might be the answer, i guess so.

Comment: it doesn't matter if this is Swing or not since the principles are the same.

Comment: Note that your first line of the question is wrong, a MouseListener is *not* a Thread. It is just some sort of callback object given to Swing and executed by Swing (which happens to execute it on another thread than your main thread, but that doesn't make the MouseListener a thread by itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to access the component on which the user clicked and disable it during the processing of the `MouseListener`. This way it doesn't accept new clicks. This would have the additional benefit of giving the user visual feedback that he is not supposed to click on the component at this time.

You can access the component through the `MouseEvent`:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
  event.getComponent().setEnabled(false);
  try {

    // ....

  } finally {
    event.getComponent().setEnabled(true);
}
```

In general though you shouldn't do too much computation in the Swing event listener thread, because Swing also needs it for processing other events and painting. You should use separate Threads for doing actual work and just start them in the MouseListener. You can also use an ExecutorService to simplify this.
It would still be a good idea to disable the gui component during the whole computation in order to give the user feedback.

***Edit:***
This solution of course depends on Swing. Any similar solution depends on the details of your GUI library, so if you use your own GUI library, you are one your own.

You can of course use a general solution involving separate threads for doing the work. I really recommend an `ExecutorService` here, were you don't need to care about the details and just submit tasks to execute. You can then have a simple volatile boolean variable which indicates whether the action is currently being executed and new clicks should be ignored.

Comment: thank you actually i can not access the component as it could be anything like chrome, windows media player etc, i just hook into system dll to get clicks. And in my implementation everything is CLI based without any Swing GUI involed at this point, basically in my logic i use JNA to get active window title, compare it to previous values and then ignore if it is the same (for multiple clicks over same component), otherwise call another method if active component is different.

Comment: Wait a minute, you are not using Swing at all? You need to tell this in the question. It has the tag "swing" and mentions names of well-known Swing classes, so I assumed that Swing is the one calling your code. If you don't use Swing, you probably shouldn't be using the Swing classes, as this could be very confusing to future readers of your code.

Comment: so for now i have implemented it with a simple if(boolean){new Thread().start()}, where in the thread i set the boolean false, and once finished set it back to true

Answer (score 2):

**Updates:** See Phillip's comments as to why this doesn't work for Swing!

It's unfortunate that you don't have access to the `eventListener`. The ideal solution would be to unregister the callback while it is being executed.

**<strike>Here's a solution</strike> that emulates unregistering the callback function while it is being executed**, assuming you want queued clicks to go away:

```
private AtomicBoolean engaged = new AtomicBoolean(); // thread-safe boolean

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){
    if (!engaged.get()) {
        engaged.set(true);

        // your logic here

        engaged.set(false);
    }
}
```

The [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) acts as a test-and-set lock preventing multiple threads concurrently running the pressed event callback. Queued presses will be dissipated during the lock.

Comment: i have tested it but it seem to have no affect on the output, may be i am missing something but i will try again in the morning, it's 3:30am here, thanks

Comment: This has no effect, because Swing is not multi-threaded. All events are executed sequentially in the same thread, so when the `mousePressed` method is called, the previous calls always have already ended.

Comment: And generally it would be very important to put the `engaged.set(false)` call into a finally block. Otherwise any exception or early return will permanently disable the component.

Comment: See my answer for an (untested) solution.